# How do I transform a MultiIndex to a dataframe with one index as rows, second index as columns and another columns as values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to I convert the below multi-index dataframe:

|  |  | open | high | low | close | volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **symbol** | **date** |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4005 | 2017-12-03 07:00:00 | 38.75 | 38.75 | 38.75 | 38.75 | 2518 |
| 4333 | 2018-01-04 09:58:00 | 12.06 | 12.06 | 12.06 | 12.06 | 2000 |
| 4338 | 2018-01-22 10:06:00 | 9.22 | 9.22 | 9.22 | 9.22 | 10 |
|  | 2018-01-22 11:23:00 | 9.22 | 9.22 | 9.22 | 9.22 | 1000 |
| 4334 | 2017-12-14 08:41:00 | 9.28 | 9.28 | 9.28 | 9.28 | 2 |
| 4332 | 2018-01-02 10:19:00 | 10.30 | 10.30 | 10.30 | 10.30 | 100 |
|  | 2018-01-09 08:56:00 | 10.28 | 10.30 | 10.28 | 10.30 | 1500 |

To this table below with symbol as columns and "close" column as the value

|  | 4005 | 4333 | 4338 | 4334 | 4332 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **date** |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2017-12-03 07:00:00 | 38.75 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2018-01-04 09:58:00 | nan | 12.06 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2018-01-22 10:06:00 | nan | nan | 9.22 | nan | nan |
| 2018-01-22 11:23:00 | nan | nan | 9.22 | nan | nan |
| 2017-12-14 08:41:00 | nan | nan | nan | 9.28 | nan |
| 2018-01-02 10:19:00 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 10.30 |
| 2018-01-09 08:56:00 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 10.30 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot)

Setup

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'symbol': {0: 4005, 1: 4333, 2: 4338, 3: 4338, 4: 4334, 5: 4332, 6: 4332},
    'date': {0: '2017-12-03 07:00:00', 1: '2018-01-04 09:58:00',
             2: '2018-01-22 10:06:00', 3: '2018-01-22 11:23:00',
             4: '2017-12-14 08:41:00', 5: '2018-01-02 10:19:00',
             6: '2018-01-09 08:56:00'},
    'open': {0: 38.75, 1: 12.06, 2: 9.22, 3: 9.22, 4: 9.28, 5: 10.3, 6: 10.28},
    'high': {0: 38.75, 1: 12.06, 2: 9.22, 3: 9.22, 4: 9.28, 5: 10.3, 6: 10.3},
    'low': {0: 38.75, 1: 12.06, 2: 9.22, 3: 9.22, 4: 9.28, 5: 10.3, 6: 10.28},
    'close': {0: 38.75, 1: 12.06, 2: 9.22, 3: 9.22, 4: 9.28, 5: 10.3, 6: 10.3},
    'volume': {0: 2518, 1: 2000, 2: 10, 3: 1000, 4: 2, 5: 100, 6: 1500}
})
# Recreate Multi-Index Data
df = df.set_index(['symbol', 'date'])
```

Create `new_df` with pivoted data.

```
# Reset Index and Pivot
new_df = df \
    .reset_index() \
    .pivot(index='date', columns='symbol', values='close') \
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)

print(new_df)
```

```
                      4005  4332   4333  4334  4338
date                                               
2017-12-03 07:00:00  38.75   NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN
2017-12-14 08:41:00    NaN   NaN    NaN  9.28   NaN
2018-01-02 10:19:00    NaN  10.3    NaN   NaN   NaN
2018-01-04 09:58:00    NaN   NaN  12.06   NaN   NaN
2018-01-09 08:56:00    NaN  10.3    NaN   NaN   NaN
2018-01-22 10:06:00    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN  9.22
2018-01-22 11:23:00    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN  9.22
```